# Pseudo-input for Bash's "read" variable

Tags: bash

I have a script listening for a user input like that.

```
read -p "Run? (y/[n]) " -n 1 -r

if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
    [..]
fi
```

Is there a way (upon executing the script) to already send the value which 
*read* is going to read and handle?

Comment: Send the value where?

Comment: `your_script.sh <<< "Y"` or `yes | your_script.sh`?

Comment: @codeforester what if the script has a "read" statement multiple times? Will `your_script.sh <<< "YYNY"` pick it up in the correct order?

Comment: @codeforester I think second variant should be `echo yes | your_script.sh`

Comment: @AndriiAbramov - `yes` is a command.  Check `man yes`.

Comment: @manuelgu - yes, that will work.

Comment: @codeforester wow, really. Thanks :)

Comment: `read` reads from standard input, so the answer to your question is simply "use input redirection".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`your_script.sh <<< "Y"`

---

This also supports multiple `read`'s

`your_script.sh <<< "YNYYNNY"`

Comment: @hek2mgl No they don't

Comment: missed the `-n1`